# google maps with Laravel4 (add post for every map object)

Tags: google-maps, laravel

I need to put on GoogleMap markers by clicking on them below the map should open them description (post from category). How possible connect google map objects and posts in Laravel 4? What solutions can you recommend for this?

Link to image http://postimg.org/image/y1m5mp9m1/

Comment: I understand your English is rough but it doesn't make a lot of sense what you're describing. Can you provide more details or perhaps draw up an image?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your request? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Can solve with googlMapper. Check more- http://www.tisuchi.com/add-google-map-laravel-googlmapper/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I completely understood your question due to your rather poor English, but I'll try my best.

First of all, have you checked the docs first? Google has a very extensive documentation on their Maps API. Check the documentation here: [Google Maps API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/)

Make sure Laravel loads the Maps API in the layout/view, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY">
</script>
```

Then make sure to initialize the map, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I recommend creating a separate JavaScript file for this (ex: maps.js).
The `map-canvas` in  `document.getElementById("map-canvas")` describes which element ID to apply the map on. Make sure it has a height & width set, else it won't be shown.

If I understand you right, I think you want to add multiple markers based on database records of Posts. One approach (which I use) is by creating a JSON array of the database records and creating a marker for each record. It will look something like this:

```
<!-- Sets the JavaScript variable db_markers to the json array of $markers -->
<script>var db_markers = {{ json_encode($markers) }}</script>
```

Then you want to create a marker and info window for each item in the json array, this will look something like this:

```
var marker, x, infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

for (x = 0; x < db_markers.length; x++) {
        var id = db_markers[x];
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(id.lat,id.lng);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        title: id.name,
        map: map
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, x) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent("<b>Title: " + db_markers[x].title);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, x));
}
```

If you don't understand something, feel free to comment and I will reply ASAP. But check the documentation too, it's really helpful. Google also has a YouTube channel where their developers explain you how to use the API, links:

- [Gettings started with the Google Maps Javascript API](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILkXO9RLhhfhlIgG9W6S4PF)
- [Google Developers Youtube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleDevelopers/)